# How do I make my executable files smaller?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I use visual studio 2019, and one thing I've noticed was that my output files are very large. I'm using release, and have set optimization to favor small code. I've also disabled generating a manifest file and debug info. However, even after these changes, the following code's executable file was **394 KB**.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{

}
```

Something is clearly wrong, but I'm not sure what. I'm not asking for much; just that this particular code be less than 100 KB. Can someone help me? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: When compiling this code in another project with the **exact same** project properties, the executable file was only 57 KB. The `.vcxroj` files were also the same (at least for `Release|x64`, which are used in both projects). [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eXqZyxIMtsWPdb2Tr0izlyceXgCHgwzp?usp=sharing) are the vcxproj files.

Comment: Are you linking with the static libraries (/MT) or the DLL's (/MD)?

Comment: Most of the time, a large executable is caused by linking a large static library or having large blocks of static data.  Your example doesn't show signs of either, but I'd start by commenting out `#include <Windows.h>`.

Comment: You should also consider defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` if you include Windows.h to avoid pulling in a ton of extra stuff.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm using /MT, but changing this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: "*I'm not asking for much; just that this particular code be less than 100 KB*" - then forget using C++ and write the program directly in assemby instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom unfortunately, that didn't change anything

Comment: @MilesBudnek That just leaves out a bunch of declarations that slow down compilation, it has no effect on the size of the executable.

Comment: Good, that eliminates one variable.  The only conclusion is that the C++ runtime library is incredibly bloated.  Since you can't write a C++ program without it, it seems you're stuck.

Comment: Try generating a link map (`/Fm: <map_file>`).  That might tell you something.

Comment: In my few quick tests, `/MT` vs `/MD` makes a dramatic difference - 200k vs 11k.  I suggest you double-check your own results.  Enabling optimisation helps a bit too, but not much.  My tests conducted with VS 2017.

Comment: Show all your build flags, since they matter.

Comment: @supsm How did you get that number? If I create a new Win32 empty project, then add your .cpp as posted, and change to static linking (`/MT`) the release builds come out at 80K (x86) and 95K (x64), without any external runtime dependencies. They both get a lot smaller if using the shared CRTs (`/MD`).

Comment: Interestingly, in a separate project (with different build flags), the code is only 57 KB. I'm pretty sure everything (but the optimization) is the same, though. The other project favors speed, not size, and the first project favors size, so I'm honestly not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @supsm Nobody will be able to help if you don't post the code and the .vcxproj file.

Comment: @dxiv the code was already up there, and now theere is a link to the .vcxproj files.

Comment: @supsm The *release* builds of both "*good*" and "*bad*" as you posted them are 79K (x86) and 93K (x64). The debug builds of "*good*" are a lot smaller than "*bad*" simply because they are set to `/MDd` (dynamically linked CRT) instead of `/MTd` (static), but then the size of debug builds is not something one would normally look at.

Comment: Windows executables are often much larger than Linux executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole time I was editing the settings, I was editing the settings for `Release`, when my active configuration was still `Debug`. I've accidentally discovered this when I found that `std::filesystem` didn't work on the other project, even though the standard was set to C++17. Here is an image of what I forgot to have done.
I'm new to these different settings in Visual Studio, and assumed that editing the settings for `Release` meant that it was going to be set as the active configuration.[image]

Answer (score 0):

After I set `Properties-> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library` to `Multi-threaded DLL(/MD)` and set `Release`, the exe becomes `9kb`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was discussed in the question's comments, and didn't make a difference to me.

Comment: In my answer, I have mentioned `set Release` . Because when you set `Release`, `Release` will automatically optimize your code. I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.